# CUDA how to create arrays in runtime in kernel in shared memory?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have the task of large number of threads running, each doing a small matrix multiplication. All the small matrices have been loaded to the global memory. I wish to improve performance by letting each thread load its small matrices into shared memory, and then compute the product. But the problem is that I do not know the sizes of the matrices during compile time. So I cannot create variables as in `__shared__ double mat1[XSIZE][YSIZE]`. On PC, I would have made a dynamic allocation. But I do not know if I could do it on the shared memory. If calling `malloc` in a kernel would allocate only in global memory (assuming such a call is possible), that does not help either.

Is there a way to declare arrays during runtime in kernel? Is there any other way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare dynamically sized  shared memory allocations in CUDA, like this

```
__global__ void kernel()
{
    extern __shared__ double *mat1;
}
```

And then launch your kernel like this

```
kernel<<<grid,block,XSIZE*YSIZE*sizeof(double)>>>();
```

This is discussed in more detail in the CUDA programming guide.

Comment: This method allows allocation of the same amount of memory to each of the thread dynamically. I have to populate each thread with differently sized matices, sizes whose upper and lower bounds I do not know yet.

But thank you very much for the reply and the reference.  It is a good starting point.  Yes, it has been discussed in the programming guide in section B.16, as I found out from your hint.

Comment: No, it allocates shared memory to each *block* dynamically. Shared memory has block scope in CUDA, not thread scope.